# How do I reference / import a derivation from a file in Nix?

Tags: nix

I'm trying to use this project: https://github.com/mpickering/old-ghc-nix

I'm assuming I'm meant to 'import' the `ghc.nix` (which generates a derivation?):

**shell.nix**:

```
with (import <nixpkgs> {});
# let ghc = nur.repos.mpickering.ghc.ghc841;
let ghc = import /home/chris/temp/old-ghc-nix/ghc.nix;
in haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
  inherit ghc;
  name = "myEnv";
  buildInputs = [ pcre ];
}
```

However this gives me an error of:

```
  ...
  error: cannot coerce a function to a string, at /home/chris/fromLaptopt/usbflash/Haskell/CeriumYankeeAvocado/shell.nix:6:3
  ...
```

How do I "execute" the function / build the derivation?

---

**ghc.nix**:

```
{ stdenv
, fetchurl, perl, gcc, llvm_39
, ncurses5, gmp, glibc, libiconv
}: { version, url, hash, ...}:

# Prebuilt only does native
assert stdenv.targetPlatform == stdenv.hostPlatform;

let
  libPath = stdenv.lib.makeLibraryPath ([
    ncurses5 gmp
  ] ++ stdenv.lib.optional (stdenv.hostPlatform.isDarwin) libiconv);

  libEnvVar = stdenv.lib.optionalString stdenv.hostPlatform.isDarwin "DY"
    + "LD_LIBRARY_PATH";

  glibcDynLinker = assert stdenv.isLinux;
    if stdenv.hostPlatform.libc == "glibc" then
       # Could be stdenv.cc.bintools.dynamicLinker, keeping as-is to avoid rebuild.
       ''"$(cat $NIX_CC/nix-support/dynamic-linker)"''
    else
      "${stdenv.lib.getLib glibc}/lib/ld-linux*";

in

stdenv.mkDerivation rec {

  name = "ghc-${version}-binary";

  src = fetchurl {
      url = url;
      sha256 = hash;
    };

  nativeBuildInputs = [ perl ];
  buildInputs = stdenv.lib.optionals (stdenv.targetPlatform.isAarch32 || stdenv.targetPlatform.isAarch64) [ llvm_39 ];

  # Cannot patchelf beforehand due to relative RPATHs that anticipate
  # the final install location/
  ${libEnvVar} = libPath;

  postUnpack =
    # GHC has dtrace probes, which causes ld to try to open /usr/lib/libdtrace.dylib
    # during linking
    stdenv.lib.optionalString stdenv.isDarwin ''
      export NIX_LDFLAGS+=" -no_dtrace_dof"
      # not enough room in the object files for the full path to libiconv :(
      for exe in $(find . -type f -executable); do
        isScript $exe && continue
        ln -fs ${libiconv}/lib/libiconv.dylib $(dirname $exe)/libiconv.dylib
        install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib @executable_path/libiconv.dylib -change /usr/local/lib/gcc/6/libgcc_s.1.dylib ${gcc.cc.lib}/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib $exe
      done
    '' +

    # Some scripts used during the build need to have their shebangs patched
    ''
      patchShebangs ghc-${version}/utils/
      patchShebangs ghc-${version}/configure
    '' +

    # Strip is harmful, see also below. It's important that this happens
    # first. The GHC Cabal build system makes use of strip by default and
    # has hardcoded paths to /usr/bin/strip in many places. We replace
    # those below, making them point to our dummy script.
    ''
      mkdir "$TMP/bin"
      for i in strip; do
        echo '#! ${stdenv.shell}' > "$TMP/bin/$i"
        chmod +x "$TMP/bin/$i"
      done
      PATH="$TMP/bin:$PATH"
    '' +
    # We have to patch the GMP paths for the integer-gmp package.
    ''
      find . -name integer-gmp.buildinfo \
          -exec sed -i "s@extra-lib-dirs: @extra-lib-dirs: ${gmp.out}/lib@" {} \;
    '' + stdenv.lib.optionalString stdenv.isDarwin ''
      find . -name base.buildinfo \
          -exec sed -i "s@extra-lib-dirs: @extra-lib-dirs: ${libiconv}/lib@" {} \;
    '' +
    # Rename needed libraries and binaries, fix interpreter
    stdenv.lib.optionalString stdenv.isLinux ''
      find . -type f -perm -0100 -exec patchelf \
          --replace-needed libncurses${stdenv.lib.optionalString stdenv.is64bit "w"}.so.5 libncurses.so \
          --replace-needed libtinfo.so libtinfo.so.5 \
          --interpreter ${glibcDynLinker} {} \;

      sed -i "s|/usr/bin/perl|perl\x00        |" ghc-${version}/ghc/stage2/build/tmp/ghc-stage2
      sed -i "s|/usr/bin/gcc|gcc\x00        |" ghc-${version}/ghc/stage2/build/tmp/ghc-stage2
    '';

  configurePlatforms = [ ];
  configureFlags = [
    "--with-gmp-libraries=${stdenv.lib.getLib gmp}/lib"
    "--with-gmp-includes=${stdenv.lib.getDev gmp}/include"
  ] ++ stdenv.lib.optional stdenv.isDarwin "--with-gcc=${./gcc-clang-wrapper.sh}"
    ++ stdenv.lib.optional stdenv.hostPlatform.isMusl "--disable-ld-override";

  # Stripping combined with patchelf breaks the executables (they die
  # with a segfault or the kernel even refuses the execve). (NIXPKGS-85)
  dontStrip = true;

  # No building is necessary, but calling make without flags ironically
  # calls install-strip ...
  dontBuild = true;

  # On Linux, use patchelf to modify the executables so that they can
  # find editline/gmp.
  preFixup = stdenv.lib.optionalString stdenv.isLinux ''
    for p in $(find "$out" -type f -executable); do
      if isELF "$p"; then
        echo "Patchelfing $p"
        patchelf --set-rpath "${libPath}:$(patchelf --print-rpath $p)" $p
      fi
    done
  '' + stdenv.lib.optionalString stdenv.isDarwin ''
    # not enough room in the object files for the full path to libiconv :(
    for exe in $(find "$out" -type f -executable); do
      isScript $exe && continue
      ln -fs ${libiconv}/lib/libiconv.dylib $(dirname $exe)/libiconv.dylib
      install_name_tool -change /usr/lib/libiconv.2.dylib @executable_path/libiconv.dylib -change /usr/local/lib/gcc/6/libgcc_s.1.dylib ${gcc.cc.lib}/lib/libgcc_s.1.dylib $exe
    done

    for file in $(find "$out" -name setup-config); do
      substituteInPlace $file --replace /usr/bin/ranlib "$(type -P ranlib)"
    done
  '';

  doInstallCheck = true;
  installCheckPhase = ''
    unset ${libEnvVar}
    # Sanity check, can ghc create executables?
    cd $TMP
    mkdir test-ghc; cd test-ghc
    cat > main.hs << EOF
      {-# LANGUAGE TemplateHaskell #-}
      module Main where
      main = putStrLn \$([|"yes"|])
    EOF
    $out/bin/ghc --make main.hs || exit 1
    echo compilation ok
    [ $(./main) == "yes" ]
  '';

  passthru = {
    targetPrefix = "";
    enableShared = true;
  };

  meta.license = stdenv.lib.licenses.bsd3;
  meta.platforms = ["x86_64-linux" "i686-linux" "x86_64-darwin"];
}
```

Comment: Ahh, the question is much more answerable as-edited. So you have a function accepting imports, returning a *second* function taking arguments `version`, `url` and `hash`. You can probably expect to need to pass the ghc... well, *version*, *url* and *hash* to that second function, after making sure the first one is called with the derivations for the various dependencies you picked up from nixpkgs (or able to default them).

Comment: BTW, is there a reason you're going straight to `ghc.nix`, and not letting the project's `default.nix` pull a definition out of the accompanying JSON files for whichever version you actually want?

Comment: Well, many thanks for the answer (that is now deleted?) - I think I'm on the right track to solving it now (so it definitely was helpful). And yes that default.nix is probably what should be used - giving it a go now.

Comment: I deleted the answer so I could edit it to actually be successfully tested with the extra details you added; you'll notice it's back now. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, some generic notes *not* specific to `old-ghc-nix`: If a `.nix` file you import starts with `{...}:`, that `...` is the definition of an attrset used as a function argument; you need to actually *call* the imported function with that argument to get... well... whatever that function evaluates to.

Now on to the specifics. :)

---

`old-ghc-nix` provides a `default.nix` that looks up definitions for your old GHC versions in the accompanying JSON files. It makes sense to use that entry-point -- if you directly inherit `ghc.nix`, you need to provide the version, checksum and URL for the specific version of GHC you want to build.

Personally, I would write this as:

```
let
  pkgs = (import <nixpkgs> {});
  ghcOld = (import ../old-ghc-nix) { inherit pkgs; };
in with pkgs; haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
  ghc = ghcOld.ghc841;
  name = "myEnv";
  buildInputs = [ pcre ];
}
```